# How to calculate the average of two files using awk and grep

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have the 2 following files:

points:

```
John,12
Joseph,14
Madison,15
Elijah,14
Theodore,15
Regina,18
```

teams:

```
Theodore,team1
Elijah,team2
Madison,team1
Joseph,team3
Regina,team2
John,team3
```

I would like to calculate the average points of each team.
I came up with a solution using only 2 `awk` statements. But I would like to do it in a more efficient way (without using `for` loops and `if` statements).

Here is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }
      FNR==NR { a[FNR] = $1; b[FNR] = $2; next } { for(i = 0; i <= NR; ++i) { if(a[i] == $1) print b[i], $2 } }' teams points > output.txt
```

In this first `awk` command, I am separating the teams (team1, team2, team3) from the names and created a new file containing only my teams and the proper points for each team (and therefor the necessity of using a `for loop` and an `if statement`).

Secondly:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=" "; 
              count_team1 = 0; 
              count_team2 = 0; 
              count_team3 = 0
              average_team1 = 0; 
              average_team2 = 0; 
              average_team3 = 0 } 

        /team1/  { count_team1 = count_team1 + 1; average_team1 = average_team1 + $2 }
        /team2/  { count_team2 = count_team2 + 1; average_team2 = average_team2 + $2 }
        /team3/  { count_team3 = count_team3 + 1; average_team3 = average_team3 + $2 }


      END { print "The average of team1 is: " average_team1 / count_team1;
            print "The average of team2 is: " average_team2 / count_team2; 
            print "The average of team3 is: " average_team3 / count_team3 }' output.txt
```

In this second `awk` command, I am simply creating variables to store how many members of each team I have and other variables to have the total number of points of each team. I is easy to do since my new file `output.txt` only contains the teams and the scores.

This solution is working but as I said before I would like to do it without using a `for` loop and an `if` statement. I thought of not using `FNR==NR` and use `grep -f` for matching but I didn't get any conclusive results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk only:

```
$ awk -F, '
NR==FNR {                 # process teams file
    a[$1]=$2              # hash to a: a[name]=team
    next
}
{                         # process points file
    b[a[$1]]+=$2          # add points to b, index on team: b[team]=pointsum
    c[a[$1]]++            # add count to c, index on team: c[team]=count
}
END {
    for(i in b)           
        print i,b[i]/c[i] # compute average
}' teams points
team1 15
team2 16
team3 13
```

**Edit:** A solution without a `for` loop in the `END`:

If the teams file is sorted on the team, you can avoid the `for` loop in the `END`. As a bonus the teams are outputed in order:

```
$ awk -F, '
NR==FNR {                # process the points file
    a[$1]=$2             # hash to a on name a[name]=points
    next
}
{                        # process the sorted teams file
    if($2!=p && FNR>1) { # then the team changes
        print p,b/c      # its time to output team name and average
        b=c=0            # reset counters
    }
    c++                  # count 
    b+=a[$1]             # sum of points for the team
    p=$2                 # p stores the team name for testing on the next round
}
END {                    # in the END
    print p,b/c          # print for the last team
}' points <(sort -t, -k2 teams)
team1 15
team2 16
team3 13
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is indeed a very efficient and elegant solution. I will keep trying to find a way without a `for` loop but your solution seems like a very good alternative!

Comment: Avoiding the `for` loop seems like a spurious complication. Why do you insist that it can and should be avoided?

Comment: See my update. A solution without the `for` loop. Downside is that the teams file needs to be sorted on the team.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this

```
awk -F, '
$2 ~ /^[0-9][0-9]*$/ {
  team_sum[team[$1]]+=$2
  team_score_count[team[$1]]++
  next
}
{
  team[$1]=$2
} 
END { 
  for (team_name in team_sum)
    print "The average of " team_name " is " (team_sum[team_name]/team_score_count[team_name])
}' teams points


The average of team1 is 15
The average of team2 is 14
The average of team3 is 13
```